# Sonar plugin to parse Velocity templates to check code quality

Tags: liferay, velocity, sonarqube

Is there any Sonar plugin to parse velocity templates to check the code quality?

I am using Liferay portal and I have lot of Liferay themes which uses velocity templates as template engine. I want to get the metrics for those Liferay themes.

I have tried to get the metrics using Sonar, but the problem is they dont parse .vm files. I was successful to get the metrics for Liferay Portlets, but I am stuck with Liferay Themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We haven't heard of such a plugin, but if you ever find (or code) one, please let us know on the Sonar user mailing list, thanks!